# Django: How to sort Query set based on another function outside of class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to sort my Post objects based on a function that gets the score of every object. My score function is:

```
def score(up, down):
    return up - down


z = log(max(abs(score), 1), 10)
```

And I was trying to get the QuerySet by using:

```
Post.objects.all().annotate(score=score('up','down')).order_by('-score')
```

However, this does not seem to be working. and I get various errors. I researched and it seems you cannot use any functions other than the ones provided by Django Database functions.

What would be the most efficient way to do this and how can I achieve the queryset sorted based on each object score?

**EDIT** I am trying to write functions that uses more advanced mathematical calculation which are not possible to do with `F` that's why I wanted to know how I can do a python function on a query set?

Comment: The annotation happens in database level and your function `score(...)` is in Python level. To sort the queryset, you have to make the annotation expression which is compatible with your DB

Comment: How can I achieve this? Should I convert queryset to list?

Comment: What is up and down here? Show your model

Answer (score 0):

considering your `up` and `down` is two different integer field meaning two separate columns in your table you can do this with `F Objects`

```py
from django.db.models import F

scores = Post.objects.annotate(score=(F("up") - F("down"))).order_by('-score')
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your response, but after looking at this I realized I can use this only for simple mathematical calculations, that's why I want to do it in a python way in order to be able to do more.